Django Templates - How can I have correct Root vs App Lookup
How can I have view load the templates from the corresponding app (root vs child)?
Here's the full structure:

Create django project - universe
Created an app - let's call it earth.
Created a (container) template for / -> universe/universe/templates/main.html
Created a (container) template for /earth -> universe/earth/templates/main.html
Created a (content) template for / and /earth at universe/universe/templates/index.html and universe/earth/templates/index.html respectively.
In universe/universe/views.py, I have:
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  context = {}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)


In universe/earth/views.py, I have the same:
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  context = {}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)



When I run this, I get an error TemplateDoesNotExist at /. Why are templates not found?
If I update universe/universe/settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
  ...
  'DIRS': [
    BASE_DIR / 'universe/templates'
  ]
]

only the universe templates are picked up.
How can I ensure that when I refer to the correct index.html based on the app?

Digging a bit deeper, I noticed the following:
When loading /, the universe/views::index is loaded but the template from earth is picked up because that's the first in INSTALLED_APPS.

Interstingly, the contrib.admin has no issues at all.

Check the linked duplicates. There's multiple ways Django looks for templates. The first duplicate explains that. The second explains how to prevent collisions in template names.

If you have app wise templates directories then you need to specify all the directories in DIRS. So, that it got picked up.
TEMPLATES = [
  ...
  'DIRS': [
    BASE_DIR / 'templates',
    BASE_DIR / 'earth/templates',
    ...

  ]
]

Also, If you have same name template in more than one directory then in view you have to mention the folder name for which your want to render the template.
In your case:
# In universe/universe/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  context = {}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)

# In universe/earth/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  context = {}
  return render(request, 'earth/index.html', context)


Since I want to have at least index.html, I added all the directories and tried to resolve using relative path. It doesn't work.
It looks for earth/templates/universe/index.html

I just misinterpreted the project and app, I thought that universe  and earth both are your app, but  universe  is a project. I've updated the answer please check it.
we just need to give the folder prefix for the templates inside the app's templates director, It's not required for the templates inside project's app directory.
